# Line segment between 2 points

Tags: google-earth

I have to lat/lon Points. I want to draw a line segment between the 2 (in kml), but I don't see functionality in Google Earth to do this. `LineString` is not it. Surely I am missing something.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns:ns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
  <Folder>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-107.980362141, 31.872060174</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-107.963280345, 31.80230482</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <LineString>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>-107.980362141, 31.872060174, 0  -107.963280345, 31.80230482, 0</coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <Icon>
        <href>redBorder.png</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>31.82103476</north>
        <south>31.78357488</south>
        <east>-107.91400752</east>
        <west>-108.01255317</west>
      </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

Comment: Why doesn't a LineString using the two points work for you?

Comment: Because it doesn't draw a line between the 2 points. What I get is a line segment at each point.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't constructing it correctly.  Please add a code snippet to your post showing what is not working.

Comment: I added some code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [KML LineString help](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring):

> coordinates (required) Two or more coordinate tuples, each consisting
>   of floating point values for longitude, latitude, and altitude. The
>   altitude component is optional. Insert a space between tuples. Do not
>   include spaces within a tuple.

Remove the spaces within your coordinates. This works:

```
    <Placemark>
      <LineString>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>-107.980362141,31.872060174,0  -107.963280345,31.80230482,0</coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
```